# Applying different styles to several instances of a Polymer 2.0 web component

Tags: css, polymer, shadow-dom, polymer-2.x, custom-element

I have created a web component using Polymer 2. Its code is transpiled to ES5 using the *es5-bundled* preset. The component is deployed on a CDN and imported on third-party pages that do not use Polymer.

Below is a usage example:

https://noticeable-widget-demo.firebaseapp.com/issues/shadycss/index1.html

There are 3 instances of the web component *noticeable-widget*.

I can apply with success a custom CSS class if the style is defined inside *custom-style*. However, the 2 other instances are not displaying at all once the style is applied. If I remove the *custom-style* definition, then all instances display their default style properly:

https://noticeable-widget-demo.firebaseapp.com/issues/shadycss/index2.html

Any idea why this happens? how could I apply different styles to different instances of the same custom element? and how to keep default component styling to work when a CSS class is defined?

Also, if I do not put the *style* definition in *custom-style*, then the defined CSS classes have no effect on Chrome. Why? After [reading the documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom#custom-style), I understood *custom-style* is there for browsers not implementing Shadow DOM v1 but Chrome 61 is, right?

Comment: Ca peut venir de ton explorateur, tu as essayé de le mettre à jour ? J'ai essayé dans Firefox et Chrome et je vois aucun problème. La 1ère et la dernière instance sont plus petites et rouges par rapport à la 2ème qui est un peu plus grosse et avec le gradient orange c'est ça ? Aussi, as-tu essayé d'importer `polymer` plutôt que `polymer-element` ? Le fait d'importer Polymer ça importe d'autres mécanismes, comme la possibilité d'utiliser des mixins css (avec `@apply`) qui sinon n'est pas supporté dans tous les explorateurs.

Comment: @user544262772 Oops, the links are pointing to the wrong resource. I have performed an updated Yesterday evening without updating the link here on my post. It explains why you were not getting the same behaviour as me. If you retry you should now see the problem. FYI, I am using Chrome 61 which is the latest stable version at this date. Also, I discussed with a Polymer team member and for him also it seems to be a bug with shadycss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to a bug with shadycss:

https://github.com/webcomponents/shadycss/issues/130